# Tag para incluir uma fonte de referência

Tags: html5, css3

pode ser uma pergunta besta, mas não estou encontrando resposta nas minhas pesquisas. estou construindo uma página web em html5 sobre polpas de frutas e estou inserindo informações de outros site e quero deixar a fonte da informação para que os usuários saibam a origem desta. Há alguma tag que posso deixar a fonte da pesquisa em destaque? Qual seria uma formatação ideal em css?

Segue abaixo o link da página que estou desenvolvendo:
[Página sobre polpas de frutas](https://pakato14.github.io/curiosidades/abacaxi.html)

Comment: Talvez a tag [`cite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite)?

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar conforme este exemplo:

```
<blockquote cite="http://developer.mozilla.org">
  <p>Esta é uma citação tirada da
  Mozilla Developer Center.</p>
</blockquote>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote